# How to access jQuery in HTML 5 web worker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-worker

I am unable to to access jQuery inside an HTML5 [web worker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker). Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Just curious... what are you trying to access from jQuery?

Comment: I loathe the day when you start needing synchronized blocks to access a dom element :)   WHY MY $('div') take 1 minutes to return?!

Comment: I was under the impression that webworkers don't have access to the DOM.

Comment: @Marc, I have some functions which access Jquery a lot. This is why I needed jquery. Also what about Jquery ajax requests?

Comment: @Marc - they don't, or atleast should'nt have, my impression is that webworkers is best used for external scripts calcuting things or doing other extensive work that you can now do "externally" to avoid onsite scripts using a long time, hanging etc. And why would you ever need a webworker to do an ajax request, which is asynchronous ?

Comment: @adeneo, It means I only need to use plain Javascript. But It will  suffer from browser combatiblities.

Comment: jQuery is plain javascript? I'm pretty sure you could include it in a webworker script, but not sure everything, like DOM manipulations and Ajax would work out of the box.

Comment: @adeneo, But it covers the issues of browser compatibilities.

Comment: If it where only that simple. But yes, it irons out some incompatibilities between browsers, among other things.

Comment: Most compatibility problems that it handles are DOM issues - with no DOM access, those problems are gone. @user960567 still didn't mention any specific function he needs - I have strong suspicion he just has a habit to include jQuery everywhere.

Comment: "access jquery" is the poorly defined part of this.  This whole question needs some love.  1 moment.

Comment: how about passing the variable `jQuery` when you do `postMessage()` like so `.postMessage(jQuery,ajaxurl,otherData)`? will it not suffice?

Answer (score 27):

## tl;dr: include [this script](http://fel.8u.cz/workerrjs/main/workerFakeDOM.js) before jQuery

JQuery initally accesses lots of `document` properties to check for browser features. `document` is not defined in Worker and you actually cannot create `Document` instance in web workers at this moment. JQuery isn't prepared for that - as you could see in comments on your question, nobody seems to understand what would you do with JQuery without DOM.

Since, as I said, JQuery needs `document` to initialise, I created a dummy fake document object. This object acts as real document during JQuery tests:

```
var document = self.document = {parentNode: null, nodeType: 9, toString: function() {return "FakeDocument"}};
var window = self.window = self;
var fakeElement = Object.create(document);
fakeElement.nodeType = 1;
fakeElement.toString=function() {return "FakeElement"};
fakeElement.parentNode = fakeElement.firstChild = fakeElement.lastChild = fakeElement;
fakeElement.ownerDocument = document;

document.head = document.body = fakeElement;
document.ownerDocument = document.documentElement = document;
document.getElementById = document.createElement = function() {return fakeElement;};
document.createDocumentFragment = function() {return this;};
document.getElementsByTagName = document.getElementsByClassName = function() {return [fakeElement];};
document.getAttribute = document.setAttribute = document.removeChild = 
  document.addEventListener = document.removeEventListener = 
  function() {return null;};
document.cloneNode = document.appendChild = function() {return this;};
document.appendChild = function(child) {return child;};
```

Beware that this fake document is only meant to allow jQuery to load, it won't allow any real DOM operations.

### Example usage:

```
importScripts("workerFakeDOM.js");
importScripts('jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
console.log("JQuery version:", $.fn.jquery);
```

### [Test script](http://fel.8u.cz/workerrjs/main/jquery.html)

Allows you to try various versions of JQuery with my script.

### [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3kf3e55/2/)

Check that you're using `http://`, my domain doesn't work with `https://`.

### [Download as script](http://fel.8u.cz/workerrjs/main/workerFakeDOM.js)

Comment: great workaround. note: this only works for jquery 2+

Comment: I found this didn't work for me unfortunately, using 2.2.0.min, the error in the jquery file just moved to another line.

Comment: Yes, this does not work anymore for `jQuery 3.1.1`. I have added my answer that works for jQuery 3.1.1

Comment: you saved my day @Tomáš Zato

Answer (score 16):

The answer of Tomáš Zato was correct, but no longer works with newer jQuery version. I added some more for jQuery 3.1.1:

```
var document = self.document = { parentNode: null, nodeType: 9, toString: function () { return "FakeDocument" } };
var window = self.window = self;
var fakeElement = Object.create(document);
fakeElement.nodeType = 1;
fakeElement.toString = function () { return "FakeElement" };
fakeElement.parentNode = fakeElement.firstChild = fakeElement.lastChild = fakeElement;
fakeElement.ownerDocument = document;

document.head = document.body = fakeElement;
document.ownerDocument = document.documentElement = document;
document.getElementById = document.createElement = function () { return fakeElement; };
document.createDocumentFragment = function () { return this; };
document.getElementsByTagName = document.getElementsByClassName = function () { return [fakeElement]; };
document.getAttribute = document.setAttribute = document.removeChild =
    document.addEventListener = document.removeEventListener =
    function () { return null; };
document.cloneNode = document.appendChild = function () { return this; };
document.appendChild = function (child) { return child; };
document.childNodes = [];
document.implementation = {
    createHTMLDocument: function () { return document; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Has anyone tried the jQuery - No DOM Edition? https://github.com/kpozin/jquery-nodom.

This is a small subset of the jQuery library intended for use in Web Worker contexts, where most of the browser API does not exist.

This is achieved primarily by modifying jQuery build instructions (Makefile) to only include the non-DOM modules.

This might help resolve the issue as this build has no DOM dependency, which is a hurdle when importing jQuery in webworker. Will try to provide some sample code soon for this

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice plugin to use Web Worker with jQuery by one of jQuery's own leaders. Check out [his plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/rwldrn/jquery-hive).

Comment: No it's not, it adds jQuery wrapper on `Worker` in main thread. I guess 5 people just upvoted this answer without even clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Does using:

```
importScripts("jQueryWhatever.js");
$.blahblahblah();
```

Not work as expected?  I suspect it will load jQuery without trouble, but most of the calls associated with good-ole $ will not work as expected as there is no DOM access inside a WebWorker.

Comment: Gives the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined'.

Comment: Sounds about right.  There isn't a lot of reason to import jQuery into webworker land.

Comment: Also gives the same error for `document`, which is not defined either.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use [**Cheerio**](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

> Fast, flexible & lean implementation of core jQuery designed
>   specifically for the server.

You will simply need to [browserify](http://browserify.org/) the module, and loading [the resulting file](https://wzrd.in/standalone/cheerio@latest) into your web worker. Then, you will be able to parse your string document and query it like jQuery does:

```
$ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>')
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery 3.3.1**

I used [Luke Vo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43178720/14452348)'s code and had to add some extra. I placed this function in my webworker and works great:

```
    const webWorkerJQueryFix = () => {
    document = self.document = { parentNode: null, nodeType: 9, toString: () => { return "FakeDocument" } };
    window = self.window = self;
    const fakeElement = Object.create(document);
    fakeElement.nodeType = 1;
    fakeElement.toString = () => { return "FakeElement" };
    fakeElement.parentNode = fakeElement.firstChild = fakeElement.lastChild = fakeElement;
    fakeElement.ownerDocument = document;

    document.innerHTML = "";
    document.head =
        document.body =
        fakeElement;
    document.ownerDocument =
        document.documentElement =
        document;

    document.createElement =
        document.getElementById =
        document.getElementsByClassName =
        document.getElementsByTagName = () => { return [fakeElement]; };

    document.appendChild = (child) => { return child; };

    document.createDocumentFragment = () => {
        this.appendChild = document.appendChild;
        return this;
    };

    document.getAttribute =
        document.removeChild =
        document.addEventListener =
        document.removeEventListener =
        document.setAttribute = () => { return null; };

    document.cloneNode = () => {
        this.cloneNode = document.cloneNode;
        this.lastChild = {
            checked: false,
        }
        return this;
    };

    document.childNodes = [];
    document.implementation = {
        createHTMLDocument: () => { return document; }
    }
}
```