# How to test if jQuery 3.0 beta is Promises/A+ compatible in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-3

According to [jQuery 3.0 Beta Released](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/)

> jQuery.Deferred is now Promises/A+ compatible
>   jQuery.Deferred objects have been updated for compatibility with Promises/A+ and ES2015 Promises, verified with the [Promises/A+ Compliance Test Suite](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests).

---

> [How To Run](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests#how-to-run)
>
> The tests can run in either a Node.js environment or, if you set
>   things up correctly, in the browser.

How to run the tests in browser, without `nodejs` to verify ?

---

Note, have not yet achieved running tests in browser without `nodejs`. @JaredSmith 's assistance was essential to running tests at all using `nodejs`.

Comment: Please ask a single question per post only.

Comment: You can easily put jQuery's deferred implementation in a nodejs module and test it there, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Bergi Have little experience with `nodejs` or `nodejs` modules . _"if you set things up correctly, in the browser."_ Thus the present inquiry . Updated OP to single Question

Comment: To "set things up correctly, in the browser" requires running browserify to make the test suite's node modules importable. The catch is that browserify uses node, so either way you'll have to learn some node.

Comment: @Bergi Would the tests at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23744774/ and http://jsfiddle.net/jdiamond/kqv3m/ from https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970 suffice as tests to check if version 3.0.0-beta meets compliance with Promises/A+ specification?

Comment: @guest271314: No, those don't offer full coverage by far. They can serve as an indicator that something changed since jQuery 2.x, and in the right direction, but they're not equivalent to the test suite. And never forget that tests cannot prove compliance, they only can show noncompliance.

Comment: @Bergi Have not been able to get node to install browserify. How to convert tests to version that can be run in browser without node? Or how to create an adapter without node equivalent to adapter expected by tests?

Comment: This is actually quite a large project. If you're having Node troubles, then your best bet is probably to make an `html` page with Mocha, Sinon, and Underscore included in the head, then copy-paste the unit tests from the repo into the document, then write an adapter to match the expected promise construction interface.

Comment: @acbabis Can you post demonstration of solution described at last comment as Answer?

Comment: @guest271314 That's an involved project that I'm frankly not interested in. However, I just looked at jQuery on GitHub. Turns out they've updated their `Deferred` unit test just 11 days ago: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/unit/deferred.js. Maybe this meets your requirement.

Comment: @acbabis Was able to run `deferred.js` using `QUnit` , passed each of the twenty-eight tests. Not certain if comparable to https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests?

Comment: @Bergi _"You can easily put jQuery's deferred implementation in a nodejs module and test it there, it shouldn't make a difference."_ Re-installed  `nodejs` , `browserify`, `pug`, and `promises-aplus-tests`. How to compose an `adapter` , `nodejs` module that exposes jQuery 3.0.0-beta1 `$.Deferred()` to run tests? Is it possible to port the tests to `QUnit`? Are tests at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/unit/deferred.js comparable to tests at https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests?

Comment: @guest271314: You wouldn't need `browserify` or `pug` for that. Just put jQuery in a module (or install it via npm), get a hold onto its `Deferred` object, write the adapter and expose it with the commonjs interface.

Comment: @Bergi Have not previously composed an "adapter" or a "module". What is the procedure? Should another Question be asked as to this?

Comment: @guest271314: Check the docs or a tutorial for how to write a nodejs module

Comment: @Bergi Is version 3.0.0-beta1 available at node https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery ?

Comment: @guest271314: I don't know, surely you can check yourself. If not, manually copying it into a file works just as well.

Comment: @Bergi 3.0.0-beta1 does not appear to be available, at least as far as could gather. Copy into a file, then do what? Just found this https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2152

Comment: @guest271314 An "adapter" is just a piece of code that converts one interface to another. For example, `$.ajax` is an adapter for `XMLHttpRequest`. When the A+ spec says to write an adapter, they're basically just saying to make it so the code runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adapter referenced in the comments means adapting the jQuery deferred constructor to meet the API in the [spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests). The way to do so might be as follows (taken more or less from [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/promises_aplus_adapter.js)):

```
var promisesAplusTests = require("promises-aplus-tests");
var jq                 = require('jquery');
var jsdom              = require('jsdom');
jsdom.env('<p></p>', function(err, window) {
    if (err != null) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        var $ = jq(window);
        var adapter = {};
        adapter.deferred = function() {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();

            return {
                promise: deferred.promise(),
                resolve: deferred.resolve.bind( deferred ),
                reject: deferred.reject.bind( deferred )
            };
        };
        promisesAplusTests(adapter, function (err) {
            // All done; output is in the console. 
            // Or check `err` for number of failures:
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

At which point you need to install the dependencies via npm and run the file. Note that using jquery *requires* a proper document (hence the need for jsdom).

Or you could take the easy route:

- git clone the jquery repo
- cd jquery directory
- npm install
- wait forever for it to finish, ignore all warnings
- npm test -which runs the jquery unit tests (including A+ suite)

Running in the browser, despite the glib comment in the spec readme, will involve some of work. You will need to use a commonJS module loader like browserify. Browserify will shim the native node assertion library and I believe filesystem api. Mocha should work fine in the browser. Then the above code should run.

If you want to avoid node.js entirely (and not just for running the tests)
, you'll have more work to do.

Step 1. Find or write a compatible assertion library and include it in a script tag.

Step 2. Include mocha in a script tag.

Step 3. Write your own stubs for require, assert, fs, etc. Each of those is a question in its own right.

Step 4. Use the adapter code.

Whether its worth doing all that or not to avoid node is your call.

Comment: Can you include a detailed approach to solve, for example, converting a single test to being capable of returning results in browser? Is using `require` library necessary? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate results?

Comment: Necessary? No its not *necessary*, but the alternative is to edit the source code of the tests to use something like assigning to global variables instead. You would also have to replace the assertion library with another one. Just use browserify. Or port all the tests (a la my answer to your other question).

Comment: Is `browserify` nodejs-based? The Question seeks to return expected results without using `node.js` . Can browserify be used as a standalone library?

Comment: No. Only way to do this with no node.js is to edit the source code of the tests to export to a global variable, stick it in a script tag src, have another script that calls the function via the global variable you assigned to, include the adapter code I wrote in-line, include an assertion library in another script tag, and include mocha in a script tag. That's a lot of work to avoid a few dozen megs of downloads and a couple of terminal commands.

Comment: Yes, perhaps some effort, though appears possible. Can you detail the steps in the process in a list or other format at Answer; possibly include a brief example at stacksnippets demonstrating the process? The requirement of the present Question is to be able to run the tests in the browser; at `console` or within an `html` `document`.

Comment: @guest271314 Just updated. More specific directions are beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: Missing closing `}` at IIFE. Trying approach described at Answer at command line, receiving `TypeError: adapter.deferred is not a function`

Comment: Receiving error `/tmp/jquery116312-32362-fp0l9k/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:9977 Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function` at http://requirebin.com/?gist=ce7a014d0ec638de5c13516d69a1e64e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108948/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between A+ compliant Promises and old jQuery Deferreds is that A+ Promises have proper error handling. You can verify that jQuery 3 promises now have proper error handling by running this simple test.

```js
function test(name, $) {
  var $name = $('<td>').text(name);
  var $result = $('<td>');
  var $row = $('<tr>')
      .append($name)
      .append($result)
      .appendTo('tbody');
  
  var def = $.Deferred();
  def.rejectWith(new Error("Error"));
  def.then(undefined, function() {
    $result.text('Fail').css('color', 'red'); // This will be overriden by success case
  }).then(function() {
    $result.text('Success').css('color', 'green');
  });
}

test('jQuery 1', $1);
test('jQuery 2', $2);
test('jQuery 3', $3);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var $1 = $;
  $.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var $2 = $;
  $.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-beta1.js"></script>
<script>
  var $3 = $;
  $.noConflict();
</script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Version</td>
      <td>Result</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How to run Compliance Test Suite in browser ?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm sorry, I misread the question. The answer to the question you asked is "You will have to write an adapter in order to meet the interface the test suite expects." I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How to run the tests in browser, without nodejs to verify ?
>
> ---
>
> Note, have not yet achieved running tests in browser without nodejs.
>   @JaredSmith 's assistance was essential to running tests at all using
>   nodejs.

Have been able to achieve requirement described at Question by utilizing and adjusting files at [Unofficial mirror of the WebKit SVN repository -> master -> LayoutTests -> js -> promises-tests](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/LayoutTests/js/promises-tests).

Attempted to change as little as possible. Updated `promises-tests`  version to `2.1.1` from `2.0.5` that was present at `webkit` repo; included `.js` files from other portions of repo to `resources` directory; added `jQuery-3.0.0-pre` source within `adapter.js`; commented `promises-in-workers.html` which tests `Promise` in `Worker` environment where `jQuery()` initialization checks `document` features.

Run tests by downloading [jquery-3.0.0-promises-tests-in-browser](https://github.com/guest271314/jquery-3.0.0-promises-tests-in-browser), opening `index.html` in browser.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("title, h3")
  .html("jQuery version " + jQuery().jquery + " Promises/A+ Compliance Tests");
  var tests = ["promises-tests-2-1-2.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-1-3.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-2-1.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-2-2.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-2-3.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-2-4.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-2-5.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-2-6.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-2-7.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-3-1.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-3-2.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-3-3.html"
               , "promises-tests-2-3-4.html"
               , "Promise-types.html" 
               // TODO test `jQuery.Deferred()` in `Worker` 
               // see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10491448/
               /* , "promises-in-workers.html" */ ];
  $.each(tests, function(index, test) {
    $("<iframe>", {
        width: "100%"
      }).on("load", function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          e.target.height = e.target.contentWindow
                            .document.body.scrollHeight * 1.1 + "px";
        }, 2000 * (1 + index));
        // if (index === tests.length - 1) {
        //    $(e.target.contentWindow.document.body)
        //    .prepend("<span style='font-family:Times New Roman'>"
        //               + "Promises in Workers Test</span>")
        // }
      })
      .attr("src", test).appendTo("body")
  })
});
```

[Demonstration](http://guest271314.github.io/jquery-3.0.0-promises-tests-in-browser/)