# Webpack worker-loader - import doesn't work

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, web-worker

I am making an application with React/Webpack/ES6 and I have a problem.

I'm trying to use web workers to make API calls. I have a functional thread pool to iniate my web workers and there are no problems with that.

The problem is that I am using the webpack worker-loader to create my workers and if I want to import an external library like this:

```
import MyLibrary from './path/to/MyLibrary';
```

I got an error like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I can't make it work, but according to the [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/worker-loader), I think that I'm doing it right. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you didn't share any code that might be problematic with `MyLibrary`. Normally, JavaScript error objects contain info about line and file where the error was thrown.

Nevertheless, I will take a guess about the obvious posibility: You're using `window` in `MyLibrary`. **The `window` global property is not defined in web workers!** For code that has to be worker compatible, use `self`. It will also work in normal browser context - `self` is therefore preferable to `window`.

As a side note, also do not rely on `window` not being defined in worker - some libraries define it to deal with compatibility problems. I do this too, sometimes:

```
if(typeof window != "object")
    self.window = self;
```

This is also acceptable workaround if you can't or don't want to edit the library. I did exactly this and much more to [make jQuery work in web workers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944817/607407).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that my problem is that window is not defined in web workers. The problem is that this error appear when I import, for example, the "request" module. So, how can I get rid of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error when I enabled Hot Module Replacement on webpack.

1. Disable the hot module replacement
2. Add `output.globalObject: 'this'` in the config ( More details please see [#6642](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6642) )

Hope these help you out.